# Search for multiple keywords in Safari (on iOS or OS X)

Tags: macos, ios, safari

I'm looking for a way to search for multiple keywords on Safari. I assume it's not really possible on iOS but I'd love to be able to do it on OS X at least.

Based on [this link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-browser-extensions-for-searching-multiple-words-on-a-webpage-chrome-firefox/) I've found some great examples of what I want, but those are for Firefox or Chrome, not Safari. Do you all know of any Safari-friendly alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean, find instances of multiple words in one page?

Comment: Exactly. [10 chars]

Comment: Well, you can search for two words at one (i.e. search the page for instances of "hello world") but you can't just search for "hello" and "world" at the same time with Safari. But wait. Just like with Chrome and Firefox there are extensions (you can view them all over at http://extensions.apple.com) and based on a quick search in there, I found an extension i think might help you: https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.salixworks.aftersearch-X6PUD2B742 Tell me if that helps (note that I've never actually used that extension).

Comment: That's a link to "After Search" if anyone else wants to use it, the link for some reason sends me to the search page. Anyways- it looks great, except it doesn't seem to work. Can someone else try that maybe and see if it works for them and if I have a different issue? Edit- never mind. The way that works is that after you hit enter and it googles the words it highlights them. I would like something similar to that but searching the active page.

Comment: sorry that there's really nothing there for you. Safari's extensions are pretty limited...

Comment: Yeah, only thing I don't like about it, but it's kind of important. Thanks for looking.

Comment: If you're looking for a better browser (I get the sense you're not thrilled with Safari, Chrome, or Firefox), I think I would recommend Vivaldi at https://vivaldi.com (note: I'm not affiliated with them in any way).

Comment: I actually do like Chrome a lot, I just like the features that using an iPhone and Mac together both have when using Safari. I will check out that browser though!

Comment: Firefox and Chrome both have similar open-tab sync and handoff support!

Comment: Hm, I'll have to look into that... Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem! Chrome: sign into your Google account on Chrome on your Mac via the Chrome preferences menu, then download Chrome for iOS and sign into that too. From the bookmarks screen on your iOS device, you can tap `Recent Tabs` and see tabs open on your other devices. On Chrome for Mac, go to History (Command-Y) and click on "Synced Tabs" to view tabs on your other devices. And Chrome has handoff support just like Safari (it works pretty well too). For a guide on how to set that up, head over to https://goo.gl/h6dBna. Additionally, bookmarks and saved passwords sync really well with Chrome.

Comment: And on Firefox, tab syncing works in a very similar way, but other features (like handoff) are not present.